Is this hurried effort to buy my car a scam?
I recently bought a used car to replace my wife's 20-year old Honda. By the time I went to the dealer I ultimately purchased from, I had visited 3 dealerships and test drove a bunch of cars. The sale went smoothly, relatively quick as it was late in the day and I was ready by that time. During the sale, the dealer offered only $500 for our Honda as a trade-in, saying they'd junk it. An earlier dealer had offered $750 also likely to junk it. I decided to pass, and they agreed I could leave it in their parking lot and drive the new-to-me car home.
The next day, the salesperson (let's call them B) called and asked about buying the Honda. B offered $800 + all fees for a private sale, not involving their dealership/employer. Sounds great to us, saves us hassle of advertising and prepping the car (it needs a detail and minor repairs, we need a new copy of its title). B wanted it as a 'project car', acknowledging it's old but in relatively good shape for a 20yo Honda. Just the kind of buyer we hoped to sell it to.
Here's where I get uncertain. B asked if they could pay by Cash App or Zelle, saying they'd get paid next day and would be ready to buy it. We talked through the plan - they'd pay us $800+fees and mail us the old plates (since we live an hour from the dealership), we're getting a copy of our original title, then we'll mail DMV our plates and forms to transfer title to B. Sounds fine. Two days from first conversation, B has asked a few times for me to setup Cash App so they could pay us. I asked if they're in a rush and noted that we'd like to write up a basic agreement of sale, just laying out what we discussed over the phone. They're fine with a written agreement but admitted they're eager to get it done. Their explanation was that they don't like keeping a lot of money in that account of theirs when they get paid, since they have subscriptions like Amazon drawing money from it. I didn't hassle them and said I'd get an agreement written and Cash App setup by tomorrow, but their explanation doesn't make sense to me.
I'm scratching my head at why the rush to pay us, given it'll take at least a few weeks to transfer title. They already said they don't care about titling it anytime soon, they plan to keep it home over winter to work on it and eventually use it as a local commuter. They explained how other project cars they bought were just used at a race track and had no title. So for them, it seems like giving us cash opens the door to using the car. Note that this person already has access to the car and its keys, because their employer (the dealership I bought a used car from) agreed to keep the car in their lot for a week or so until I pick it up. For all we know, they're already driving it, but that'd be their employer's bad.
Why would B be in such a hurry to pay us? Should we have our guard up more for some kind of scam? The only reasonable explanation I can think of is that they see this Honda as worth more (we hoped to get $2-4k selling it ourselves). Maybe they want to close the great deal for them before we get smart to it. We're fine getting just $800 though, skipping the work of trying to get more for it. Are there other precautions we should take? We'll get a basic agreement in place (lay out the plan as stated above, state clearly the purchase is for the car as-is, sign and date), I'll transfer funds from Cash App to our bank ASAP, we'll do the DMV plate termination, update our insurance, title transfer and all that. I'm thinking if it was a scam, it'd just be this person revoking Cash App payment and basically stealing our car, but it's not worth very much and we know their name and employer. They don't strike me as untrustworthy but I barely know them.

I don't like the not-in-a-hurry-to-title (and register) the car. Any tickets it accrues could end up with you as the still-on-the-books-owner. Ohio: title transfer must occur within 30 days of  sale or late fee will be accessed.

@mkennedy that's where I was worried and decided we at least need a sale agreement, so the exchange is in writing. In that agreement, I spell out that upon payment and receipt of our license plate, we'll transfer possession of remaining keys and file for title transfer. Once our plates are off, we'll mail in to end our registration with that vehicle. Seems like those steps address your concern, right?

Do a quick ebay search in your area, and see what similar old hondas are selling for.  ot listed-at price, what people are actually paying for the same thing.   Might be enlightening.

Why did you leave the keys with the dealership? If it were me, I would make the 2 hour drive to give them a signed bill of sale, title and take their cash (no, not Cash App-- cash). Is 2 hours of your time not worth $800?

Many states have a form for reporting the private sale of a vehicle. It doesn't transfer title, it's just a legal record that the transaction occurred between X and Y on date Z.  Even if it takes a while to get the title transferred, that form will protect you in the event that the vehicle racks up toll road charges, runs a red light camera, etc. in the meantime.

@spuck I left a key with the dealer because it was in their jam packed lot (they're in a large city), so they could move it if needed. But yes, I am going there to get paid and deliver a bill of sale and pickup the old plate, title transfer is in the works separately.

Maybe someone mistakenly sold your car and now they need to buy it from you...

For $800 plus fees, I'd drive the hour to the dealership where your car still is and have the conversation in person and do the deal there. Plus if this is an employee of the dealership, frankly you know where they work. Most scammers prefer to be anonymous!

@ThaRobster I ended up doing that, did the deal in person, no problem.

If this is a scam, it's a hard one to pull off. They can't sell or even legally drive the car without some ownership (most states require proof of registration to be available upon request by law enforcement). There's a lot of legal things that need to be done. The two key ones are (may vary some by state)

A signed bill of sale. Can usually be a basic document you type up and print yourself
The car title, usually with your signature and to whom you are selling the car

Most likely B has another buyer lined up. Either someone saw it on the lot and B thinks they will buy it, or they are a car broker who looks for used cars. You said you could get $2k-4k for it. For an $800 sale, that's a potential $3200 profit. Not a bad deal for B if they can pull it off.

We're fine getting just $800 though, skipping the work of trying to get more for it.

There's the key for you: selling your own car is not easy. If you think $800 is a good deal, I'd play ball and mail the title after you get paid. They're making money by reselling it.

"... someone saw it on the lot..." That is a thing that happens. I once bought a used car from a dealer, and I drove it off the lot not more than a couple of hours after somebody else traded it in. It still was parked in the same "customers only" space where the previous owner had left it.

If the title is not transferred and someone else drives off with it after "buying it" from the dealer, then the OP could be liable for any damages/offenses the new driver does.  If they're really in a hurry the dealer will drive the one hour to the OP and do a proper paper transfer.  There's something very suspicious about all this.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine while the title transfer is still in the works, we at least took off the old plate and have a bill of sale. If any problems came up, we'd point to that bill of sale as proof of exchange, plus the fact that in another few weeks we'll have our old plates destroyed by DMV and title transferred officially.

It sounds more like they are trying to close a bad deal before you realize it's a bad deal. That isn't what we usually mean when we say scam, though.
Or he may have some specific time or financial pressure to get this done in a hurry. But I don't see any way you can be certain of that. And if it is that urgent for him, you might want to try talking him into paying more, as the cost of expediting the transaction.

OK, that's our thinking too. It probably is a great deal for them, but we feel pretty good about it to as we don't have the time to shop it around much.

@cr0 Along the idea of financial pressure to get it done, B could have a spouse / partner who B fears will spend the money (at Amazon?) if it stays in the account too long. Allowing this possibility, the "Amazon subscription" claim may make more sense, especially if they buy online using only a debit card, not a credit card.

@MTA that is very plausible and could make sense given the little background B shared about their life. At first it just seemed like an irrational reason to me...subscriptions don't just eat up new $ in an account! But other authorized users might

This is my thinking.  You tell your friends about this and someone says, hey my daughter needs a car, I will give you $900 or $1000 for it.  They guy buying this car, may do so with the intent of flipping it.  Clean it up and sell it for $1500.

@PeteB. that is fair reasoning, but I myself have a new child and very little time for additional projects. If this guy fixes it up and flips it, I'll just take some (non-monetary) comfort in this beloved old vehicle not becoming scrap.

@cr0 Agreed, there is plenty of money to go around so if this buyer makes a bit of money flipping the car, and gives you a bit more cash in the process with no additional work then everyone wins.

Is B the same person you've talked to in person at the dealership? Have you called him back at the number on his business card to confirm? Have you seen their salesperson license (should be visible in the dealership or shown to you) to confirm their identity?
Usually cash/zelle scams are based on intangible transfers, unidentified third parties, and advance payment premise, which in your case seems not to be the case. A car is a tangible thing that can be found, and the person you've dealt with is not anonymous internet imposter but a  real person you can find as well. If you have a written contract with the person and can show the actual tangible asset in question then you'd have recourse even if the transfer is reversed or is otherwise found to be fraudulent.

Yes, B is the salesperson I bought from and first called me about buying the Honda from their work phone. Then B gave their personal # which we've used since for calls and text.

I'm thinking the same thing - most of the red flags for a scam are not there. The unexpected hurry is what made me cautious. But I haven't lived paycheck to paycheck for a long time, and it sounds like they do to some extent, so I might just not understand their perspective.

I am a little more suspicious. I don't necessarily think they are try to scam you, but they may be trying to scam their employer, and they are in a hurry to take possession and get it off the lot and the view of their employer. I'd be a bit surprised if the employer approved of employees making side deals with their customers. Is the trade in value of your car mentioned anywhere in the terms of sale for for the new to you car? Is the dealership getting made whole for not getting the car for its scrap value?

I wonder about their employer's thoughts on this, if they even know. B is a newer employee there too but has worked at dealerships for years apparently. At the end of the day, though, it doesn't seem like my concern other than if I need to give permission to B's manager for B to take our key and car that we left with the dealer (or really with B as an employee). B's manager was involved in stowing our car at their dealership. To be clear - we'll have a basic 1pg sale agreement signed with B so the transaction is in writing, and the dealer has no stake in my old car, it was not traded in.

My sale agreement with the dealership for my new car does not mention anything about my old car. We had no trade in, just cash down payment + EV tax rebate we were able to get on the purchase.

You mention a reason B may want to hurry this along: if it takes too long, their employer may become wise that their employees are running side hustles and losing them money on deals. If they had offered you $800 for the car on trade-in it would have been money in their pocket. I guess you could consider it a scam, but against their employer, not against you.

This could be a scam, not against you but against the dealership.  When you tried to trade in the car, the salesman falsely reports to his boss that the vehicle is worthless. He calls you the next day to buy it for what the dealership should have offered you for it.  Now, he can resell/auction it and make whatever profit that the dealership would have made.  Siphoning off business from your employer can be considered anything from an unethical conflict of interest to an illegal fraud, depending on the details.  You're not doing anything wrong here, but it still might be something that you don't want to get involved with.
In addition, the salesman may have violated the law in contacting you.  He got your phone number from company records and used it for his own personal uses.  Even if that's not illegal in your locale, it's at least unethical and highly inappropriate.  Imagine if he just showed up at your house or something, or kept calling you to ask for a date.  Trying to buy your car is less creepy, but it's wrong for the same reasons.  People get fired for that sort of thing.
For the reasons above, I would not do business with this guy.  Instead, I'd report him to the dealership's manager and block the guy's number.

This scenario makes sense to me, but at least to some extent it's not that bad. B is new to this business, transferring from elsewhere, and his manager accompanied us through the process. His manager was the one who gave me the news that they'd only pay $500 to scrap it. But you're right, B did contact me from his employer's phone for a personal transaction.
